# How can I implement a crouch mechanism in pygame without the crouch image overlapping the normal image?

Tags: python, pygame

i am trying to add a crouch mechanism but when i screenblit the image it is ontop of the last one

```
def player_move():
    global playerindex, player_gravity, player_surface
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        playerrect.x += 4
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        playerrect.x -= 4
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        screen.blit (player_crouch,playerrect)
    else:
        player_surface = player_movement[int(playerindex)]
```

i expected that if i did an if statment that if s is pressed i would screenblit the image and the past one would disapper until i release the "s" button but the crouch image was ontop of the normal image

Answer (score -1):

Without a minimal reproducible example, I can only guess what might be causing the issue, but here are a couple of ideas:

- You are blitting multiple times per frame, resulting in two images being drawn on top of each other. In this case, you should only need one blit statement, and change what surface you are blitting based on what action the player is doing i.e. standing or crouching.
  change

  ```
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        screen.blit (player_crouch,playerrect)
  ```

  to

  ```
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        player_surface = player_crouch
  ```

  Your game loop should contain a singular blit statement that blits the current player surface -

  ```
    screen.blit(player_surface, playerrect)
  ```

  You should not have any other statements that blit the player onto the screen anywhere in your code.
- You are not refreshing the screen. By default, pygame does not clear the screen every frame, and you will have to implement this yourself by using `screen.fill()` in your game loop, or by otherwise drawing a background before the player is drawn, *every frame*. (However, if your player can move left and right without overlapping then this is likely not the issue)

Comment: There is no difference from my answer, which apparently does not solve the problem.